# How to disable `ts` sources maps debugging

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to debug `TS` project. WebStorm automatically picks up source maps and show original `ts` files. I don't want to use `source maps` and debug generated `js` files. How can I disable usage of source maps in WebStorm?

**NOTE:** this question is not about how to disable source maps **generation**, it's about how to disable source maps **usage** during debugging

Comment: Why do you want to create the source map, but not use it?

Comment: I didn't create them, they are created by a package authors

Comment: no way; when the generated file is loaded, debugger finds the sourcemap by `//# sourceMappingURL` comment in it and then resolves original file using sourcemap. You can try deleting the comments from generated files (if you are permitted to do this)

Comment: @lena, thanks, that's sad. are there any plans to provide options for that?

Comment: you are the first user asking for such possibility; so no - no plans so far

Comment: you can try using FireFox for debugging - sourcemaps don't work when using it... You need using FireFox Remote configuration for this. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/debugging-javascript.html#d317892e172

Comment: I ran into this right now when debugging subscriptions-transport-ws package. It has sourcemaps in the dist, but the package doesn't contain the src.

Comment: The only way I found in Webstorm was also removing these comments. But VSCode can disable sourcemaps, maybe next time I'll try that editor instead - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-maps

Comment: Still not possible in 2023 :( Found issue on YouTrack, please upvote so JetBrains increases prio on this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61256/Allow-disabling-source-maps-when-debugging

Answer (score 12):

One option is to check if there's a tsconfig.json file and in it, you can disable the sourceMap generation:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false
  }
}
```

Another option, is to disable the use of source map files in your browser's debugger, for instance in Chrome you can uncheck this option:

[image]

Under Settings -> Preferences

Comment: as I mention in my question, `this question is not about how to disable source maps generation, it's about how to disable source maps usage during debugging` and I'm debugging in WebStorm, not a browser